# How do I create a term for every value of a post meta?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, loop, taxonomy

I have some information stored in post meta that I'd like to convert to terms. I'd like to create a term in a custom taxonomy for every meta value with a particular key.

I need to loop through ALL posts, gathering all values of the metavalue key.

I'm thinking the code will be like this, I'm just not sure the syntax exactly.

```php
<?php
$all_posts_with_release_year = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'release'
] );
if ( $all_posts_with_release_year->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $all_posts_with_release_year->have_posts() ) {
        $all_posts_with_release_year->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $release_year_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpcf-release-year', true );
        //Check to see if a taxonomy term with that name exists.
        if ($release_year_value exists as $taxonomy_term){
           select $taxonomy_term for $post_id;
        }else{
           create $taxonomy_term with $release_year_value;
           select $taxonomy_term for $post_id;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I realize I have two smaller questions.

1. How to create a taxonomy term in a foreach loop
2. How to select a taxonomy term for a post in a foreach loop

I'm going to see about the answers to these on the site and will post an answer if I find it, so that someone who hasn't broken this bigger question down into the smaller ones yet can find help.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I fixed the terminology you used, it didn't make a lot of sense when phrased that way, and you have to be specific or people will think you want something else entirely. E.g. Post Category is a taxonomy, but the red category is a term in that taxonomy. Or another example would be genre, genre is a taxonomy, and Rock/Pop/Jazz are terms in that taxonomy. Terms are not slugs, but terms can have slugs/descriptions/etc. You should also abandon "fields" when talking about post meta as it _heavily_ implies certain things such as using ACF. Just call them post meta.

Comment: Thanks Tom, still learning. Ok, I'll re-edit to be more clear.

Comment: Also `get_field` is an ACF function not a WordPress function, if you're using ACF to store that data then you'll need to mention that ( and it might make your question offtopic ). There are also several smaller questions inside this such as how to create taxonomy terms in code etc that have already been asked and answered on the site. Look those up and you might not need to ask this question. Likewise how to assign a term to a post in code, all of these have questions that have been answered already by other people

Comment: I fixed that `get_field`. I'm not using ACF to store that. Thanks, I'll work through this and maybe can give my own solution to help others. Thanks Tom.

Comment: to fetch post meta you should use `get_post_meta`, `get_metadata` is a lower level function, `get_metadata( 'release'` is equivalent to creating a `get_release_meta` for a `wp_release` table. I've adjusted your pseudocode accordingly

Comment: Thanks Tom. I learn alot from these. Still processing, but I see some of the code around here. Looking forward to working this little puzzle.